Calculate the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{A_n}{A_{n+1}}$
Lets $\displaystyle A_n=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^n(x)dx$, by integration by parts you get
$\displaystyle A_n=\frac{n-1}{n}A_{n-2}$:

Now, knowing this we can think of
$$
A_p=\frac{n(n-2)(n-4)...(n-k-1)}{(n+1)(n-1)(n-3)...(n-k)}A_k
$$
with $k=n-2t$ for some $t$ natural.
Doing the same with $A_{n+1}$ gives me
$$\lim_{n\to  \infty}\frac{A_n}{A_{n+1}}= \lim_{n\to
   \infty}(n+1)\frac{(n-1)^2(n-3)^2...}{n^2(n-2)^2...}K,
$$
$K$ being a constant depending if $n$ is even or odd.
So, dividing on both side of the fraction by $n$ I get $$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{A_n}{A_{n+1}} =
\lim_{n\to \infty}(n+1)\frac{(1-\frac{1}{n})^2(1-\frac{3}{n})^2...}{1(1-\frac{2}{n})^2...}K=\infty
$$
Is this reasoning correct ?.

$A_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $A_1=1$

Why wouldn't you compute $A_0$ and $A_1$ first?

Have you considered obtaining an explicit solution for the integral in terms of gamma functions, and using the Stirling approximation?

@NEON Now I am trying to obtain an explicit solution depending only from $n$ of $A_n$ depending if n is even or odd

With Laplace’s Method, $\displaystyle\quad\operatorname{A}_{n} \stackrel{{\rm as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim} ,\sqrt{,{\pi \over 2n},},$

Given that (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^n(x)dx=\frac12B\Big(\frac{n+1}2;\frac12\Big)=\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{n+1}2\Big)\Gamma\Big(\frac12\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{n+2}2\Big)}$$
$$\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^n(x)dx}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n+1}(x)dx}=\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{n+1}2\Big)\Gamma\Big(\frac{n+3}2\Big)}{\Gamma^2\Big(\frac{n+2}2\Big)}=\frac{n+1}2\left(\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{n+1}2\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{n+2}2\Big)}\right)^2,\to1$$

Usiing @Svyatoslav's result, take logarithms, use Stirling approximation and re-exponenetiate to get $$\frac{A_n}{A_{n+1}}=1+\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{3}{8
n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

For this recurrence relation, maybe it's also worth mentioning that for general nonzero $A_0,A_1$ we have $R_{2n}:={A_{2n+1}\over A_{2n}}\to{A_1\over A_0}{\pi\over 2}.$ E.g., $A_0=1,A_1=2$ gives a nice sequence with $R_{2n}\to\pi.$ (Proof by Stirling's formula.)

Your initial recurrence $$A_n=\frac{n-1}{n}A_{n-2}$$ is sufficient to deal with the problem. You have perhaps gone overboard by trying to use the explicit formula for $A_n$ based on this recurrence.
Observe that the integrand decreases as $n$ increases and hence $$A_{n+2}<A_{n+1}<A_n$$ and therefore $$\frac{A_{n+2}}{A_n}<\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}<1$$ ie $$\frac{n+1}{n+2}<\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}<1$$ By squeeze theorem the ratio $A_{n+1}/A_n\to 1$.
